# Strange Angular PWA Service worker behaviour when deployed

Tags: angular6, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

This issue has taken up all my day, and I can't figure out whats going on

I can see that my service worker is registered , however "sometimes" when I click offline in developer tools the ServiceWorker for my domain just disappears!!

But this is the main problem when I reload the app I see the following behaviour.

You can see the ngsw.json is loaded twice and the main.js is loaded 3 times! main.d3ae2084xxxx && main.bbe5073dxxxx && then main.d3ae2084xxxx again!

[image]

If I inspect the response of both ngsw.json requests you can see that both show main.d3ae2084xxxx as the correct version of main.js but it still loads main.bbe5073dxxxx...

First ngsw.json request

[image]

Second ngsw.json request

[image]

Whats even more frustrating is the actual loaded version is the previous main.bbe5073dxxxx...!!!!

If anyone has any ideas how this can be happening please let me know.

**Update...** So found out about this excellent little endpoint

```
https://you-app-url/ngsw/state
```

This will give you lots of debug information about your service worker.

In my case this

> Driver state: EXISTING_CLIENTS_ONLY (Degraded due to failed
>   initialization: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork):
>   https://dev-xxxx.net/main.eb8468bb3ed28f02d7c2.js: expected
>   b5601102b721e0cf777691d327dc965d40d1c96e, got
>   83c18fdb4a5942c964a31c119a57e0b8e16fe46e (after cache busting)

So looks like this is going to be a CDN issue of some sort in my case, will update with an answer when I know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably resolved this by now, but I had the same issue which turned out to be due to the CDN (Cloudflare in my instance) was optimising the content.

In Cloudflare the key option is 'Auto minify' that needs to be disabled.